# Selecting in jQuery nested .children()

Tags: jquery

I am learning jQuery, and I was wondering what is the difference between these two selectors:

```
    $('#puzzleGrid table tr td img');
```

and

```
    $('#puzzleGrid').children('table').children('tr').children('td').children('img');
```

Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I personally would probably use this: `$('#puzzleGrid table img');`.  In general (there are occasionally exceptions for performance reasons), you don't want more things in the selector than are required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selector - as pointed out by Fraicio Matte -

This first one will use the DOM QSA when available, which is a quadrillion times faster than the second example full of function calls' overhead.

```
$('#puzzleGrid').children('table').children('tr').children('td').children('img');
```

is very specific to getting children elements of the previous element

and this - [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('#puzzleGrid table tr td img')
```

Will find any "table" descendants(any table element under) of element with id=puzzleGrid.. and any descendant tr of the found tables.. and so on.

The equivalent to the first one would be using `>` [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$('#puzzleGrid > table > tr > td > img')
```

Comment: Add that the first one will use the DOM [QSA](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) when available, which is a quadrillion times faster than the second example full of function calls' overhead.

Comment: So one could say a child is a direct descendant like `#puzzleGrid -> table` in contrast to `#puzzleGrid -> div -> table` ?

Comment: @yoshi Read up the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/children/), `.children` only traverses down 1 level in the DOM tree. Use `.contents()` if you need recursive stuff.

Comment: lol I didn't expect the "quadrillion" part included, but according to my statistics it's about right. `=]` +1

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Just read up the docs of child-selector provided by wirey and I think this quote illustrates it pretty well "The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level descendants."

Comment: Yup, it works in the same fashion, both are child selectors after all. `=]` Only difference is that jQuery's children selector will work in IE6 which doesn't support the CSS version of it. **edit:** making it clearer, the CSS child selector won't work in IE6 when used in CSS/style, a child selector CSS string supplied to the jQuery selector should take care of it as Sizzle will fill in the IE gaps.

Comment: I'm not feeling confident to call both of them a child selector as I think of a child as a top-level descendent. Mathematical spoken children is a subset of descendants. Well.... like real life :3

Comment: @yoshi That's right, childs are descendants in the first level below its parent in the DOM tree. `.children` and `>` will respect that.

Comment: So... descendants can skip levels in the DOM whereas children are only first-level descendants?

In other words, would $('#puzzleGrid img') work?

Comment: @Kore Yup that's right. `=]` You'll end up selecting ALL `img` elements which are descendant of `#puzzleGrid` then.